# Application compiled in .Net 4 framework will not run on Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I compiled my application to use .NET Framework 4 because I need this to work on XP and Server 2003 that does not support .NET Framework 4.5.  The issue is it now runs fine on the XP and 2003 servers but not on my Server 2012.  Server 2012 has .NET 4.5 and from what I have read .NET 4.5 is backwards compatible with .Net 4

Below it the error I receive on my 2012 Server:

---

Unhandled exception has occurred in your application if you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

The System cannot find the file specified.

Details:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at MyApplication.Form1.DirectoryExporter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18449 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MyApplication
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/administrator.DM/Desktop/MyApplication.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

---

Here is the code that is being called at this time:

```
public string get_regValue(string userroot, string subkey, string keyname, string app)
        {
            string userRoot = userroot;
            string subKey = subkey;
            string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subKey;

            string regValue = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyName, keyname, null);
            regValue = regValue + app;

            return regValue;
        }

        private void DirectoryExporter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Button to Launch the Directory Exporter
            string regKey;
            RegistryKey openKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Dell");
            // Checks for key, if null (empty) get 32 bit key
            if (openKey == null)
            {
                // 32 bit key
                regKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Dell";
            }
            else
            {
                // 64 bit key
                regKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Dell";
            }

            var regvalue = get_regValue(regKey, "Migrator for GroupWise", "AdminInstallDir", "gwdirapp.exe");
            Process.Start(@regvalue);
        }
```

Comment: @Cory: No, you shouldn't need to. .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade for .NET 4, so it should be fine...

Comment: I agree with and you can not even install .NET 4 on a server 2012 as it is part of the OS

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suspect this has nothing to do with the version of .NET you're using. After all, from the stack trace you can clearly see that your code *is* executing:

```
at MyApplication.Form1.DirectoryExporter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I suspect that the issue is one of permissions - that whatever you're trying to do is failing under Windows Server 2012 due to it running in a more locked down environment.

Alternatively, it may be that you're trying to start a process that exists on your development machines, but not on the server. We can't really tell without seeing the code - but you should basically look carefully at what you're doing in `DirectoryExporter_Click`, particularly when you call `Process.Start`. Examine which executable you're trying to run, then check that it's present on the server, and that the user you're running as has permission to execute it.

Comment: This server is where the application exist. If I compile this in .NET 4.5 it works on this server with no other changes but then it will not work on my older machines

Comment: @JRMackz It is very possible that the path to the process you are trying to start is different on the server.  The exception message said that the file could not be found.  It is either missing or not where you expect.

Comment: @JRMackz: That sounds very unlikely to me, given the exception you're receiving. It would help if you'd show us your code though...

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the code to the orignial question

Comment: @JRMackz: And what is the value of `regvalue` in the situation where this is failing? (And why are you using `@` in the `Process.Start` call?) If you're not logging it yet, you should do so.

Comment: @JonSkeet The regvalue is only returning gwdirapp.exe and not the full path. 

I found that the section "RegistryKey openKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Dell");" is not returning the value on even though it is there. 

I am using the @ in the Process.Start call as this is what the tutorial showed me but at this point I am not getting that far along in the code

Comment: @JonSkeet I got this to work by editing the section to look like below:

RegistryKey openKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Dell");

Comment: @JRMackz: You should either make those single slashes, or remove the @.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by editing to code as shown below:

```
public string get_regValue(string userroot, string subkey, string keyname, string app)
{
    string userRoot = userroot;
    string subKey = subkey;
    string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subKey;

    string regValue = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyName, keyname, null);
    regValue = regValue + app;

    return regValue;
}

private void DirectoryExporter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Button to Launch the Directory Exporter
    string regKey;
    RegistryKey openKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Dell");
    // Checks for key, if null (empty) get 32 bit key

    if (openKey == null)
    {
        // 32 bit key
        regKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Dell";
    }
    else
    {
        // 64 bit key
        regKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Dell";                
    }

    var regvalue = get_regValue(regKey, "Migrator for GroupWise", "AdminInstallDir", "gwdirapp.exe");
    Process.Start(regvalue);
```

Comment: Just for clarity, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` was removed from the `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey` call.